# Posting to multiply related tables Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I would like to create my own endpoint for POST request to two related tables. I have two tables *User* and *Userattribute*.

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=180)
    roles = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    firebase_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    progress_sub_step = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    step_available_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    progress_step = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    last_login_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'

class Userattribute(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name = 'attribute')
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The table *Userattribute* contains the field *user* which is OnetoOne to *Id* primary key from *User* table.

I tried to implement POST to two tables in **serializers.py** In the commented section there is a create definition which works perfectly for me. However, I wouldlike to move it to ***views.py*** as *register_in_course* endpoint

**serializers.py**

```
class FilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ['tytul', 'opis', 'po_premierze']

class UserattributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Userattribute
        fields = ['user', 'attribute']


class UASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Userattribute
        fields = ['attribute']


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attribute = UASerializer(many = False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'firebase_id', 'attribute']

# This is what workks perfectly for me, and I want to move it to views.py
# VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
# def create(self, validated_data):
#     attribute_data = validated_data.pop('attribute')
#     user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
#     Userattribute.objects.create(user=user, **attribute_data)
#     return user
```

Current **views.py**:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail = False, methods = ['post'])
    def register_in_course(self, request, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_object()
        user = User.objects.create(email=request.data['email'],
                        name=request.data['name'],
                        firebase_id=request.data['firebase_id'])
        user_id = User.objects.filter(firebase_id = request.data['firebase_id'])['id']
        attribute = Userattribute.objects.create(user = user_id, attribute = request.data['attribute']['attribute'])
        user = user.attribute.add(attribute)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many = false)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Using endpoint ***register_in_course*** to POST I get following error:

*Expected view UserViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.*

***urls.py***

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'userattribute', views.UserattributeViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`

Comment: I have just added

Comment: The issue is because you are calling `self.get_object()` but the view is defined with `detail = False`. Is there a reason why this was done?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by calling `get_object` in a view that is defined with `detail=False`:

```
    @action(detail = False, methods = ['post'])
    def register_in_course(self, request, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_object() # The problem is caused by this line
```

It seems you don't need this data, as you are using `request.data`.

So you can define your view like this:

```
    @action(detail = False, methods = ['post'])
    def register_in_course(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.create(
            email=request.data['email'],
            name=request.data['name'],
            firebase_id=request.data['firebase_id']
        )
        Userattribute.objects.create(
            user=user, 
            attribute = request.data.get('attribute', {}).get('attribute', {})
        )
        return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
```

Comment: Now I get:
QuerySet indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: It's a completely different issue caused by this line: `User.objects.filter(firebase_id = request.data['firebase_id'])['id']`. You are using `['id']` on a queryset. But if you reached this, then that means my answer worked ;)

Comment: Do you know how to rewrite 
`def create(self, validated_data):
     attribute_data = validated_data.pop('attribute')
     user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
     Userattribute.objects.create(user=user, **attribute_data)
     return user`
to views.py? I am really stuck

Comment: I think you should create a new question for that, as it is a different issue, and would make this post too messy with different questions about different things. Also do let me know if this answer is still relevant or not

Comment: But It still the same question. How to create endpoint in views.py to post to multiply tables. I attached working create() function which I used in serializers, and I would lie to move it to views.py.

Comment: I got error
MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/users/register_in_course/
'attribute'

Comment: What is your request data? Depending on that, you can fix how to get `attribute`

Comment: {
    "email": "michal@gmial.com",
    "name": "Michal",
    "firebase_id": "1241412412412",
    "attribute": {
        "attribute": 4
    }
}

Comment: Can you try with `attribute = request.data.get('attribute', {}).get('attribute', {})`

Answer (score 0):

i removed one line user_id variable and changed attribute variable. please check, maybe it should solve your problem, because you have already have Assigned variable as a User object..

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail = False, methods = ['post'])
    def register_in_course(self, request, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_object()
        user = User.objects.create(email=request.data['email'],
                        name=request.data['name'],
                        firebase_id=request.data['firebase_id'])
        attribute = Userattribute.objects.create(user = user, attribute = request.data['attribute']['attribute'])   # changed this line
        user = user.attribute.add(attribute)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many = false)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shotiko for you help
I used this, but I got 
MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/users/register_in_course/
'attribute'

Comment: hey, have you solver that problem? you should do like that -> change your code attribue = request.data.get('attribute', False)   or request.POST.get , if it dont takes attribute default will be false. check and reply if it helps.